# Redis Cache Server - Multiple Website Ennvironments

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am new to redis but I installed a windows version today. I was able to use the StackExchange.Redis c# client (https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)

But now I have a slight problem. I have one site with multiple environments that use the same redis server, so I am running into a key collision issue.

What's the best way to support a multiple environment app on one redis server. I read about Database Index, but it seems thats frowned upon based on my research on some dated articles. In 2016, whats the recommended approach?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something essential, it is effectively *impossible* to secure redis in a multiple application environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, there're 2 solutions:

> Assign an exclusive database for each app

Just as you mentioned, you can store data into an exclusive database for different apps. With the [select](http://redis.io/commands/select) command, you can switch between these databases.

> Each app has different key prefix

If you want/have to store all data in a single database, you can use the key prefix to avoid key collision. For example: keys for app1 has a prefix: `app1`, and keys for app2 has a different prefix: `app2`.

```
// set keys for app1
set app1:key1 value
set app1:key2 value
// ...
// set keys for app2
set app2:key1 value
set app2:key2 value
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the key prefix idea, great suggestion

Comment: Note that multiple databases are not supported on a clustered configuration